# How can I display the current date and time in my C# windows form application's text property?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to show the current date and time in live in the title of my C# windows form Application.

My resource says that I need to use datetime.now.tostring(); to do so, but I don't know how. Any ideas ?

Comment: Share your code what you need ?

Comment: You're new here - welcome! Ok, I'm going to answer this but _before you post next time_ please make an effort to solve it _first_. Then when you run into a specific problem, post the code you've written so far.  Read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) because it's a guide on how to get most helpful answers and how to create a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). These are the things missing from your post that are causing it to receive downvotes .

Answer (score 1):

You want to display the current date and time in the title bar of your Form using its `Text` property. The *simplest* way to update the time *continuously*  is to use `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` which issues its ticks on the UI thread.

Using *other* timers (e.g. `System.Timers.Timer`) or updating UI controls from background workers generally can be tricky. If your WinForms app might end up being ported to an iOS or Android device, there are better more-portable alternatives. A good practice for handling events generated by backgound tasks is to use [BeginInvoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke) to ensure that the control is updated on the UI thread.

In this straightforward case however, simply handle the `Tick` event:

- Obtain the current timestamp using the static [DateTime.Now](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.now) property.
- Format the `Text` property using [DateTime standard format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings).

---

**Minimal Example**

[image: screenshot]

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm() => InitializeComponent();
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        _timer.Tick += onTimerTick;
        _timer.Start();
    }

    private void onTimerTick(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var now = DateTime.Now;
        Text = $"Main Form - {now.ToShortDateString()} {now.ToLongTimeString()}";
    }

    System.Windows.Forms.Timer _timer= new System.Windows.Forms.Timer { Interval= 1000 };
}
```

Comment: why not use a timer?

Comment: Yeah in fact I was just updating that.

Comment: There are caveats though. Thing One is: You have to be careful of _which_ timer. This is OK for `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` but not `System.Timers.Timer` for example. But I agree with you I've simplified the answer.

Comment: Thing Two is: I'm accustomed to writing portable timer code that will work on Android and iOS also and so my first thought was to post what I use in production code. Thank you for the comment, I absolutely agree with you in this instance.

Comment: @DanielA.White there's one other reason one might opt for 'not' using a Timer. This is something I often see in new-coder code. Basically, doing work (like an HTTP ping) on a one-second timer tick that might take more than one second to execute. So if you have your background task, synchronously execute the work (whether it takes 1 or 10 seconds) and then wait you're interval then it's safe.

Answer (score 1):

Simply just add a timer and write this code on timer tick event:

```cs
private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

and then just enable the timer:

```cs
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    timer.Enabled = true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this, it will work on runtime:

```cs
public partial class FormMain : Form
{
    public FormMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Text = "Your title here";
    }
}
```